# Converting V/m data into Vo in coaxial cable TEM mode

Tags: coax

In coaxial cable we have the following formula shown below.

a = 0.819mm

My simulation says that the maximum is 7240V/m

I want to find the Vo value from simulation. The input power in CST is 0.5W so I tried to find Vo by calculation as shown below.

\$P=V^2/Z_{tem}\$

\$Z_{tem} = \sqrt(mu_o/eo*er) = 377/\sqrt(2.2) = 254.17\$

\$V = \sqrt(P*Z_tem) = \sqrt(0.5*254.17) = 11.27V\$

\$7247*2*pi*0.819*10^{-3}=37.29V\$
$$

So how do I find Vo from the CST simulation?

[image]

[image]